# Showing a gif image while form is being processed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-boot

I am working on a spring web application where I have a login page but I want to show a gif image while the form is being processed. Please anyone can guide me through the best way to achieve this.

this is the part in my HTML page with a javascript function inside.

```
<div class="loginbox">
<img src = "images/login2.jpg" class="avatar" >
<form  id="myForm" action="login" method='POST' onsubmit="return validate();" >
<div th:if="${param.message != null}" class="alert alert-info" th:text="${param.message[0]}">message</div>
<div th:if="${param.error != null}" class="alert alert-danger" th:text="${session[SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION]}">error</div>
<p>Username</p>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your Email">
<p> Password</p>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
<div>
<input id="myBtn" type="submit" name="submit"  value="Login"> 
<img id="loadingImg" src="../images/loading.gif" style="display:none;" alt="LOADING PLEASE WAIT....">
</div>
</form>
</div>
 <script th:inline="javascript">
 function validate() {
    if (document.f.username.value == "" && document.f.password.value == "") {
        alert(/*[[#{message.username} + #{message.password}]]*/);
        document.f.username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.f.username.value == "") {
        alert(/*[[#{message.username}]]*/);
        document.f.username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.f.password.value == "") {
        alert(/*[[#{message.password}]]*/);
        document.f.password.focus();
        return false;
      }
   }
  </script>
```

I tried to add something in js like this function

```
function validateGif(){

     var  myForm= document.getElementById('myForm');
     var  loadingImg= document.getElementById('loadingImg');

      myForm.style.display='none';
      loadingImg.style.display='block';

    setTimeout (function(){
        myForm.style.display='block';
      loadingImg.style.display='none';
    }5000);

}
```

But I know it doesnt work correclty. I want to show the gif image as long as the form is submitting and if there is some validation errors to stop the gif and show the error. However the gif image should be loading all time the to the redirection after authentication.

What is the best way to go through this.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: On form submit you're just validating there's nothing async there for a loading spinner. If you make an API request you can show a spinner and then hide it when it completes. Btw you have a syntax error here `}5000);`

Comment: Have to agree with @DominicTobias what you're doing here is a simple form validation which tbh should be complete within milliseconds, probably faster than even would be reasonable to show an image. If you want to do this on submit (of your data) you could, but  you would want to send your form data to your parsing script, with AJAX and then show the image and hide it when if the ajax call was successful. We can provide you with help on that but would need to know that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @pj100 Yes that is what I wanted to do, even if it is fast I need to include the AJAX to show the image and hide it, but dont know how.. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example with jQuery.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (event) {
  // prevent the default action of the form, i.e. submitting 
  event.preventDefault() 

  if (document.f.username.value == "" && document.f.password.value == "") {
      alert(/*[[#{message.username} + #{message.password}]]*/);
      document.f.username.focus();
      return false;
  }
  else if (document.f.username.value == "") {
      alert(/*[[#{message.username}]]*/);
      document.f.username.focus();
      return false;
  }
  else if (document.f.password.value == "") {
      alert(/*[[#{message.password}]]*/);
      document.f.password.focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
  else{
    // serialize your form data
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    // show image 
    $('#loadingImg').fadeIn();
    // run ajax request
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        type: 'POST', // if using jquery 1.9 or earlier
        data: formdata,
        url: 'your/form/action',
        success: function (data) {
           $('#loadingImg').fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Musa too.. Since I have another function validate, that helps to show errors, Now it is working to see the Image gif but the errors not. how to integrate my old validate function with this ajax thing. and where we should trigger it, from form?

Comment: I just updated it to do this in a somewhat literal sense. you have a block of `if` statements, just adding `else` would cause the ajax function to trigger if none of your validation steps are met. However, I would consider looking into doing this with a function and a callback, this should suffice.